# Update when relevant rows are not present in the source table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, merge-statement

I have a merge statement like this:

```
MERGE DESTINATION
USING SOURCE WHERE <Some_Conditions>
WHEN MATCHED AND <Some_Conditions> THEN DELETE
WHEN MATCHED UPDATE
WHEN NOT MATCHED INSERT
```

This is working fine but I have one more condition i.e. I have to update the rows in destination when their entry is not present in the source.

Ex.

**Source**

```
Column1 Column2 Column3
-----------------------
A        A       A
B        B       B
```

**Destination**

```
Column1 Column2 Column3
-----------------------------------
B        B       <Some_Calculation>
D        D       <Some_Calculation>
```

Now, as there are no rows in source for `D`, I have to modify `Column 3` in destination with some calculation. But as merge is giving only the three options of `delete`, `update` and `insert` when rows matched or not.

How can I implement this functionality in the above statement?

**Edit**

Editing question with my comments below:

*In the above example which I have given above is running then It is updating `B` and inserting `A` into destination table. But I want to update `D` also even when it is not present in the source table*

Comment: @Mahmound In the above example which I have given above is running then It is updating B and Inserting A in destination table. But I want to Update D also even when it is not present in the source table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe read the documentation for [`MERGE`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx):

```
MERGE 
[ TOP ( expression ) [ PERCENT ] ] 
[ INTO ] <target_table> [ WITH ( <merge_hint> ) ] [ [ AS ] table_alias ]
USING <table_source> 
ON <merge_search_condition>
[ WHEN MATCHED [ AND <clause_search_condition> ]
    THEN <merge_matched> ] [ ...n ]
[ WHEN NOT MATCHED [ BY TARGET ] [ AND <clause_search_condition> ]
    THEN <merge_not_matched> ]
[ WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE [ AND <clause_search_condition> ]
    THEN <merge_matched> ] [ ...n ]
...
```

`WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE` is what you need

Comment: Perfect ! It was all there :)